# SQL 2012 Replication Between Subscribers Across VPN

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have been assigned with setting up replication for an instance(remote instance) at a geo location that we access across a VPN. The remote instance will need to send the transactions to a local subscription/distributor (subscription 1) and then the transactions from that subscription will need to be pulled/pushed to an on-premise instance (subscription 2).

I am having issues figuring out the steps for setting up the configuration from subscription 1 to subscription 2. Input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify some of your terminology - is the local instance local to your on-premise instance or local to the remote instance?

Comment: The local instance is an on-premise instance, not the remote instance. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved as the replication will be scripted using stored procedures from the publisher (remote instance) to the subscriber (local instance) using a sql account setup for the subscription's linked connection to the remote instance.

The VPN is dedicated so there no major concerns with the VPN.

The publisher will use push method for the local subscription. Then from the local subscription a replication using the subscription (sub 1) will be pulled to the second local subscription(sub 2) that is read only.